# Bind data from db into datagrid MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatable, datagrid

I have a `DataTable` that gets its daata from an sql database,
i want to bind the information of the `DataTable` to a grid with the 
MVVM pattern.

**The way i think i should do it :**

create a Model class that represents a row in the `DataTable` values,
one `property` - for each column that i want to show in the data grid.

(if there are any alternative ways to make the model class i would like to know..)

The problem im facing is :
i don't know how to assign each cell of the `DataTable` / data from the database table , to a property of the model class,
because the model only represents one row..

**To sum it up** :

i just want to bind my database table with the UI..(and i assume the best way is through MVVM pattern..)

if someone can show me an example of implementing MVVM when the data comes from a database, it would be very helpfull!

(i know its sounds like something that could be found easily online but i couldn't find an example that helped me)

Thanks

Comment: Not MVVM but could perhaps be a useful overview of some concepts: Entity Framework Databinding with WPF @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx

Comment: Presumably you are using Visual Studio. It should let you deploy an Entity Framework  Model from your DataBase